# how to use one procedure to insert into two table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to insert value into `EVENT` table and `EventCost` table by using only one procedure.

The PK of event is `EventID` and it is the `FK` of `EventCost` table.
I tried to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for `EventID` but still fail to create the procedure.

2)Do I need to declare the v_EventID in the header for two times? (One for the Event table , one for the eventCost table)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_ADD_OVER_BUDGET_EVENT
(  V_eventID IN VARCHAR
  ,V_EventType IN VARCHAR
  ,V_EventBudget IN NUMBER
  ,V_organizerID IN VARCHAR
  ,v_CostID IN VARCHAR
  ,v_FoodBeverage IN NUMBER
  ,v_wine IN NUMBER 
  ,v_Decoration IN NUMBER
  ,v_rentalfee IN NUMBER
  ,v_facility IN NUMBER
  ,v_EventID IN VARCHAR)

AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Event 
values 
(next_eventid_seq,null,v_eventbudget,null,null,null,v_organizerID)


INSERT INTO EventCost 
values 
(next_Costid_seq,v_FoodBeverage,v_Wine,v_Decoration,v_RentalFee,v_Facility,SCOPE_IDENTITY())

End;
/
```

Comment: You want to insert into the second table `EventID` generated by the insert into the first table, is that right?

Comment: Yes,the eventID of first table and second table have to be the same.

Comment: Check the answer.

Comment: *"Do I need to declare the v_EventID in the header for two times?"* You don't even need to declare it once, as the value of `event.eventid` is generated inside the procedure from the sequence rather than being passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `returning into` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_ADD_OVER_BUDGET_EVENT
(  V_eventID IN VARCHAR
  ,V_EventType IN VARCHAR
  ,V_EventBudget IN NUMBER
  ,V_organizerID IN VARCHAR
  ,v_CostID IN VARCHAR
  ,v_FoodBeverage IN NUMBER
  ,v_wine IN NUMBER 
  ,v_Decoration IN NUMBER
  ,v_rentalfee IN NUMBER
  ,v_facility IN NUMBER
  ,v_EventID IN VARCHAR)

AS
  event_ID varchar2(64);
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Event 
values 
(next_eventid_seq,null,v_eventbudget,null,null,null,v_organizerID) returning eventID into event_ID;


INSERT INTO EventCost 
values 
(next_Costid_seq,v_FoodBeverage,v_Wine,v_Decoration,v_RentalFee,v_Facility,event_ID);

End;
/
```

P.S. Also a few notes:

1. Use `varchar2` datatype instead of `varchar`.
2. When inserting, provide the names of the columns you insert into: `insert into Event (col1, col2, col3, ...)`. In case your table structure is changed, the insert statements will still work.

Comment: I don't think that will compile - parameter `V_eventID ` conflicts with parameter `v_EventID` due to case-insensitive names. Drop the second one?